Drag and Drop de una foto con otra
Debo hacer un drag and drop de una imagen creada por una funcion ("showImage()") por encima de otra imagen ("map"). La clase "draggableImage" tiene position:absolute y el container #imageContainer position:relative. El drop debe quedar por encima del cursor y la imagen por encima del map.

este es mi codigo de javascript:
let imageCounter = 0;
function showImage() {
    // Create a new image element
    var newImage = document.createElement('img');

    imageCounter++;
    // Set the source
    newImage.src = 'icons/icon1';
  
    // Set any other attributes or styles as needed
    newImage.class = "draggableImage"
    newImage.id = 'image_' + imageCounter;
    newImage.style.width = '5%';
    newImage.draggable = true;
    newImage.alt = "image";
    // Append the new image to the "map" div
    document.getElementById('map').appendChild(newImage);
    newImage.addEventListener('dragstart', drag);
}

function drag(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("imageId", event.target.id);
    console.log(event.target.id)
}

function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageId = event.dataTransfer.getData("imageId");
    var draggedImage = document.getElementById(imageId);

    // Get the current mouse position relative to the container
    var mouseX = event.clientX - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().left - (draggedImage.width / 2);
    var mouseY = event.clientY - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top - (draggedImage.height / 2);


    // Set the new position of the dragged image
    draggedImage.style.right = mouseX + 'px';
    draggedImage.style.top = mouseY + 'px';


}

Aqui estan los divs de html:

<div id="center-container" >
    <div id="imageContainer" >
        <div id="map" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <img src="mapimages/map.png" alt="map" class="mapimage">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



y cuando hace el drop, que tiene que pasar?

Hace mucho que no hago un drag and drop pero la ultima vez que lo hice recuerdo que devia llevar una funcion drop() el js no?

cuando hace el drop, se debe poner la imagen generada donde esta el cursor. Tambien, debe estar por encima de la imagen del mapa (la que tiene la clase mapimage :p) @Yussef

@Anthonyx82 si, tenes razon, se me paso poner la funcion drop() que intente hacer funcionar, la pregunta ya esta editada para que la veas

La parte de drop para la imagen deberia ser esto para poder hacer lo que quieres
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageId = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var droppedImage = document.getElementById(imageId);
    event.target.appendChild(droppedImage);
}

